# Getting accelerometer data in the app's inactive state in the WatchOS

Tags: ios, watchos, watchconnectivity

We are developing a WatchOS companion app which records Accelerometer data. We call CMSensorRecorder.recordAccelerometer(forDuration: _) and retrieve the data by calling CMSensorRecorder.accelerometerData(from: _, to: _). So far so good. But the issue arises when we have a data for say 2 hours.

We get the accelerometer data in the SwiftUI Task or using GCD's background queue. The data we get is in the loop, enumerating the CMSensorDataList. The loop goes on when the app is active. But as soon as the Watch app goes to inactive state, say applicationWillResignActive is called, the loop is suspended. I know this is the default behaviour of the OS. But this makes our data parsing so slow that sometimes it takes an hour or so to get 2 hours data. This is making our app not user friendly. Is there a way we can keep our app alive as soon as the data is being processed? Or is there another way for faster data processing that we can send the raw data to phone using WCSession so that the data gets there as soon as recording stops?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure. Here is the sample project that illustrates the problem. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nS_iCXue3fJBC5XjGLGHBqv6Ba7Qk4-a/view?usp=sharing